# Parse save password is not working even though the user is created

Tags: android, authentication, parse-platform

So I am new to parse and I am trying to implement a simple login feature.

I am using this code

```
 ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
                newUser.setUsername(userName);
                newUser.setPassword(passwordFirst);
                newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                    AppUtils.toast(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS");
                    finish();
                    } else {
                    AppUtils.log(e.toString());


                    }
                }

                });
```

This code does create the user which i can see on the browser but it does not save the password so I can never log in. What could be the problem ? any suggestions?

As I said, the user is created in the browser but the password field remains undefined(un edited) so I can not log in.

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
EditText editText_userName;
EditText editText_passwordFirst;
EditText editText_passwordSecond;

CheckBox checkBox_terms;

Button button_signUp;
Button button_cancel;

String userName;
String passwordFirst;
String passwordSecond;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity__sign_up);



    //UI INIT
    editText_userName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_username);
    editText_passwordFirst=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_passwordFirst);
    editText_passwordSecond=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_passwordSecond);
    button_signUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_signup);
    button_cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
    checkBox_terms = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_acceptTerms);

    button_signUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity__sign_up, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_signup:

            passwordFirst = editText_passwordFirst.getText().toString();
            passwordSecond = editText_passwordSecond.getText().toString();
            userName = editText_userName.getText().toString().trim();

            if(!passwordFirst.equals(passwordSecond)){
                AppUtils.toast(getApplicationContext(),"Passwords do not match");

                break;
                 }

            if(!checkBox_terms.isChecked()) {
                    AppUtils.toast(getApplicationContext(),"Terms have not been accepted");

                    break;
                }
                ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
                newUser.setUsername(userName);
                newUser.setPassword(passwordFirst);
                newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                    AppUtils.toast(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS");
                    finish();
                    } else {
                    AppUtils.log(e.toString());


                    }
                }

                });

               // this.finish();




            break;

        case R.id.button_cancel:
           this.finish();

            break;

        case R.id.button_showTerms:

            break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Did you read the documentation>

Comment: I can't seem to edit any of the _User feature of my app. setEmail doesn't work either.

Comment: @JoxTraex Yeah, Am i missing something?

Comment: Could you show us your whole class?